# Firebase authStateChanges() doesn't trigger on Flutter hot reload but it does on browser refresh

Tags: firebase-authentication

Using Google provider with this method so I can detect logins/outs and redirect user from login page to different page:

```
 FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen()
```

For now I have it set so user state is preserved until browser closed:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.setPersistence(Persistence.LOCAL);
```

Unfortunately, Flutter hot reloads don't trigger authstatechanges() when i use Google provider from home page (home page is the login page). A manual browser refresh with F5 does seem to trigger the method (assuming it forces it to read the cookie) and it redirects as it should.

Is there a way to trigger authstatechange() manually as the google provider login screen doesnt ask for credentials on hot reload but it doenst trigger firebase authstatechanges().

Answer (score 0):

Use `startWith()` or `ConcatStream()` from `rxdart` to force the stream start
with latest auth state:

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class SomeClass {
  void init() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
      .authStateChanges()
      .startWith(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser)
      .listen(...);
  }
}
```

or with `ConcatStream`:

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class SomeClass {
  void init() {
    final authStateStream = ConcatStream([
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
      FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    ]);
    authStateStream.listen(...);
  }
}
```